# How tagging works in GIT

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a question about tagging in GIT.

Let's imagine that I am working on a repository in which I have a series of changes merged on the `master` branch and I have tagged that master branch with version `2.1.0`.

If I now make other changes and merge them also to the `master` branch, that `2.1.0` tag will catch those new merged changes or I would have to create another version as `2.1.1` (for example)?

thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: You don't tag branch you tag commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag is a pointer to a commit

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

> Git supports two types of tags: lightweight and annotated.
>
> A lightweight tag is very much like a branch that doesn’t change — it’s just a pointer to a specific commit.
>
> Annotated tags, however, are stored as full objects in the Git database. >They’re checksummed; contain the tagger name, email, and date; have a tagging message; and can be signed and verified with GNU Privacy Guard (GPG). It’s generally recommended that you create annotated tags so you can have all this information; but if you want a temporary tag or for some reason don’t want to keep the other information, lightweight tags are available too.

So if you change your branch nothing happens to your tag

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! :) so in case you want to make a safe rollback you should first remove the latest tag first, and then do the revert in the repo I think. In that way you have sync tag and changes in master. Thanks a lot again!